# NullPointerException: thrown where it's not expected

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

```
public void setSpecifications(ObservableList<Specifications> data) {
    String sql = "select * from specifications where ( bid=" + bid[0] + " or bid=" + bid[1] + " or bid=" + bid[2] + " or bid=" + bid[3] + " ) and ( mid=" + mid[0] + " or mid=" + mid[1] + " or mid=" + mid[2] + " or mid=" + mid[3] + " ) and ( vid=" + vid[0] + " or vid=" + vid[1] + " or vid=" + vid[2] + " or vid=" + vid[3] + " );";
    int colCount = 0;
    String  specVal[], paramVal = null;
    specVal = new String[]{" ", " ", " ", " "};
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount;  colIndex++) {
            rs.beforeFirst();
            paramVal=rsmd.getColumnName(colIndex+1);
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rs.next(); rowIndex++) {
                specVal[rowIndex] = rs.getString(paramVal);
            }
            data.add(new Specifications(paramVal, specVal[0], specVal[1], specVal[2], specVal[3]));
            //**NullPointerException**
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Compare.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
file:<path>.jar!/carshowroomsystem/details/compare/Compare.fxml
  at carshowroomsystem.dataInterface.Compare.setSpecifications(Compare.java:138)

  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
 ...  rest of the trace

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at carshowroomsystem.dataInterface.Compare.setSpecifications(Compare.java:138)
    at carshowroomsystem.details.compare.CompareController.addCar(CompareController.java:74)
    at carshowroomsystem.details.compare.CompareController.initialize(CompareController.java:65)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at carshowroomsystem.WelcomeController.handleCompareAction(WelcomeController.java:106)
    ... 44 more
```

It's throwing `NullPointerException` at line `data.add(...)` where I have checked all the arguments have some value! No idea what to do.
And why the trace is showing `Compare.fxml` file? It should be `.java`

Comment: Concatenating an SQL query in this way implies SQL attacks. Use prepared statements to mitigate them.

Comment: Even if `getColumnName` should return null, it shouldn't throw a NPE, because you don't call any method on the result - sure, that it's this method call that throws?

Comment: @Tiny  Still there is no way for anyone to modify these variable that might inject bad code in query and I have no idea how to make SQL statements useable with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have `String  specVal[], paramVal = null;` which initializes the `paramVal` to null. The expression `paramVal=rsmd.getColumnName(colIndex+1)` is in third part of the `for` expression, so it is executed after iteration, so the very first iteration uses `null` value for the `paramVal`. You need rewrite the code as it just doesn't make sense, and learn how `for` statement works in Java.

Comment: I thought the third part of for executes first!